# Unselect Yii2 radiolist using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2, radiobuttonlist

I am trying to unselect radio buttons using jquery in yii2. I have tried all the possible syntax to unselect radio button using jQuery.

```
  <?= $form->field($model, "radio[$component->accident_component_id]")->radioList(ArrayHelper::map(AccidentTemplateComponentData::find()->where(['=', 'accident_component_id', $component->accident_component_id])->all(),'accident_data_id' ,'accident_data_text'), ['separator'=>'<br/>','tag'=> false, 'prompt'=>'- Options -', 'class'=>"$checkClass", "id"=>"input-$component->accident_component_id"])->label(false); ?>
```

Jquery code to uncheck the radio button is below

```
  //tried using Javascript
  document.getElementByNAme('Accident[radio][$component->accident_component_id]').checked = false;

  //tried using jQuery
  $('input[name=\"Accident[radio][$component->accident_component_id]\"]').removeAttr('checked');
```

Both the above don't work. When I right click on the elements there is a hidden input with same name, I wonder if that is overwriting. The above code works fine for a normal radio button.

Any help would be great. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `<?php` to echo its variable value.

```
 //tried using Javascript
  document.getElementsByName('Accident[radio][<?php echo $component->accident_component_id ?> ] ').checked = false;

  //tried using jQuery
  $('input[name=\"Accident[radio][<?php echo $component->accident_component_id]\"?>]').removeAttr('checked');
```

Add `"` if needed like `document.getElementByNAme('Accident[radio]["<?php echo $component->accident_component_id] ?>").checked = false;`

**EDIT**

In javascript there is no method name with `getElementByNAme` it is `getElementsByName`

```
document.getElementsByName('Accident[radio][$component->accident_component_id]')[0].checked = false;
```

Comment: I don't have to echo it...because in yii2 we can register js. I can directly access those variables.. works fine when I try to retrieve values..only uncheck doesnt work